# Mapping multiple Arrays in one Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I do have two Arrays one array with list of items:
One array with string objects
and one with Array objects

```
NSArray * a=[1,2,nil];

NSArray * b=[[abc],[def],[ijk],[lmp], nil];
```

I want to return Array by mapping Array "a" object "1" to array "b" with objects "[abc],[def]"
and Array "a" object "2" to array "b" with objects "[ijk],[lmp]"

I know I can achieve it in `NSDictionary` but i want to return `NSArray` not `NSDictionary`.

or any alternative method to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by mapping? Could you show us a resulting array as you see it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are trying to describe. What does the construct `[abc]` mean? Is that a string, an of objects inside array b? And what does it mean when you map one element in array a to 2 elements in array b? Are you saying that each entry in array a corresponds to a pair of objects in array b?

Comment: Create an `NSDictionary`. The keys will be the "1" and "2" values. The values for the keys will be the arrays of arrays.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by mapping? Because an array is just a list, there's no association between objects... Also, I don't know where you got that code from but those are not NSArrays...

Comment: try [obj enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:<#^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)block#>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more about data structures knowledges?
I see that your pattern is to increase two index.
So, it's something you want?

```
NSMutableArray *object;
NSUInteger indexOfA = [a indexOfObject:@1]; // get the index of the object from A
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
   [object addObject:b[indexOfA * 2 + index]];
}
```

Then, you can pull out what you want from b.